# git push heroku master password not working in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up a rails project and initiated git..

then created heroku and added git remote..

But while using git push heroku master, a dialog box opens and asks to for a password to unlock the private key..

when i entered the heroku password, its not authenticating??

which password should i use to unlock the private key??

Answer (score 1):

The private key in question is the default SSH private key for your user account on your computer. This password might be the password to your local computer user account.

Comment: hi justice..

The private key mentioned in the dialog box is my username(email address) for heroku..

Comment: Are there any other passwords that you may have used when setting up your computer or when pushing to or pulling from other Git repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial from GitHub to generate your SSH key: http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/

Your SSH key is hidden, it won't be printed out for you to manually copy and paste. If you're a Mac user, run this command to copy your private SSH key to your clipboard:

```
$ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You'll be able just paste your SSH key to where ever you want.